# Respecting Font Ligatures in Java/Swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I've run into a problem that has me really scratching my head when dealing with Swing objects in java (and JFX as well, but I'll worry about that later...).

Here is the code that I am using to open fonts in my program. It's pretty standard.

```
public static Font getFontFromFile(String filePath) throws FontFormatException, IOException {
    File fontFile = new File(filePath);
    return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontFile);
}
```

My problem is that when I actually go to use these fonts, ligatures within them are not respected. One of the core features of my program allows users to load custom fonts, many of which have specialized ligatures. These are not being respected, and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. If the user types two characters that should reduce to a single ligature, the second character just appears normally, with no transformation taking place. When I load the fonts into any other program or text editor I'm seeing the ligatures be respected exactly as I would anticipate.

I've stripped down code where I'm actually setting the font in a few places to the absolute bare bones and I'm seeing the (wrong) behavior even in places where I'm doing something as simple as:

```
jTextField.setFont(myFont);
```

Is there some setting on import that I am missing? Or that needs to be globally flipped on the 2D graphics object? Any assistance would be really appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FOUND IT.**

Ok. So. This one was frustrating, as I had been correctly setting the `TextAttributes`, while loading fonts via a method which is plagued by a long standing bug... Ligatures are supposed to be represented in `JTextField` and `JTextArea` objects, but under certain circumstances, they will not be. There are two things to keep in mind.

1. There is an old bug (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8139741) which prevents ligatures from being respected when using the pattern

```
// BROKEN PATTERN
Font myFont = new Font(<FONT_FAMILY_NAME>, Font.PLAIN, 72);
```

Instead, the font ligatures will only be respected if it is loaded from a binary location:

```
// WORKING PATTERN
File myFontFile = new File(<FILE_LOCATION>);
Font fixed = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, myFontFile);
```

2. Once the font is loaded from binary, ligatures must be set via TextAttributes like so:

```
Map attributes = fixed.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.LIGATURES, TextAttribute.LIGATURES_ON);
fixed = fixed.deriveFont(attributes);
```

When loading fonts directly from the OS, I've taken to finding the actual font file on the system and loading it as a binary. It's cumbersome, but it functions.

Answer (score 0):

At least with respect to Java2D, I read [this - see Figure 4-13](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/spec/j2d-fonts.html#wp66677) as suggesting that Java will simply take the list of code points provided and render the glyph for each without combining to make ligatures.

Back before JavaFX 2, there used to be a boolean `ligatures` property on `javafx.scene.text.Font` that claimed to control whether ligatures were used, but that [doesn't appear to be there anymore](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Font.html).

Historically (it's been at least 7 years) I've had to parse TT/OT fonts for ligatures and do the combining manually (and sometimes even pair kerning).

Comment: Could you link me to something that shows how you're doing the manual handling? I'm really scratching my head here, and while it would obviously be best to have Swing handle this for me automatically, I am willing to implement something on my own as well.

Comment: Sorry, that was years ago and the company (that I no longer work for) owns the code.  Essentially we built a look-up table of all situations we needed to handle (e.g. "ffl" or "V" followed by small-caps "A" which needed kerning help) based on what the font definition provided, and scanned the text stream.  For ligatures we did glyph replacement, for kerning we split the string and adjusted the start point of the next piece of text.  (We also needed to do smart/correct hyphenation, so we needed to be scanning the text stream anyway.)